# Jquery datatables unable to highlight row?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to make it so that when the user clicks on a row in the table, it highlights:

I am using the jquery datatables plugin here:
http://datatables.net/

My CSS

```
.row-modified {
    background-color: '#000';
}
```

My Event Handler

```
$("#mytable tbody tr").live("click", function(event){
    console.log("Row Clicked");
  $(event.target).parent().find("td").addClass('row-modified');
});
```

What is wrong with what I am doing? (note: I am suing the default CSS provided with datatables).

Comment: does $(this).addClass('row-modified'); workjs for you instead the$(event.target).....

Comment: Just tried it and it does not work. The debug statement is printed though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.row-modified {
    background-color: #000 !important;
}
```

that's the only changed needed (removed the '' that wrapped the color , and added the !important)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:
Answer taken from - https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable(); 

$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
    else {
        table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
}); 

$('#button').click( function () {
    table.row('.selected').remove().draw( false );
});
```

});